Retrieving Some Texts in Javascript
I wanted to retrieve the first letters of a person's first name and last name using modern JavaScript syntax. Currently, I'm able to retrieve the first letter of the first name and the first letter of the last name correctly.
My problem is that if there's no "of" word, I can't retrieve it.
Here's my Jsfiddle link ----> CLICK HERE
CODE:


/* const name = "Joshua Jones of USA"; */
const name = "William Sanders";
/* const name = "Grey Charles"; */

function getUserInitials(name) {
  return /^(.).+([A-Z])\w+\sof\s.+$/.exec(name).slice(1, 3).join('');
}


console.log(getUserInitials(name));




Please don't change your requirements when people have already answered your question; instead, ask a new question. Changing the requirements invalidates given answers. Rolling back.

Not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but this solves the shown test cases:


const names = ["Joshua Jones of USA", "William Sanders", "Grey Charles"];

function getUserInitials(name) {
  return name.split(' ').map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase()).splice(0,2);
}

for (const name of names)
  console.log(getUserInitials(name));



If this doesn't satisfy your requirements, then please elaborate on those.

Sorry but what if the name is "Carlos James Thomas of Russia", it should get output as "CT"

There's no way you can bake all possible edge cases into a simple regex or one liner.

It's fine, you can add more lines

You'd have to define the exact requirements first.

I have edited my question with some samples. Let me know what do you think.

How about "Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez III, Mexico"?

Output would be "JL". since the first name is "Juan" and last name is "Lopez"

Again, without a full specification of all possible cases, there is no way to solve this.

Ok. edited my question. I've covered all the possible scenarios. Those are it.

See my comment on your question.

Ok, just marked your answer as correct. Will ask a new question. Thank you

Here is it: Can you use modern JS syntax/features?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78394269/getting-first-letters-of-first-name-and-last-name-in-js

If your test cases cover all possible formats, you can either improve your regexp:


function getUserInitials(name) {
    const matches = /^(.).*?\s+(.).*$/.exec(name);
    if (matches) {
        return matches.slice(1, 3).join('').toUpperCase();
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

console.log(getUserInitials("Joshua Jones of USA"));
console.log(getUserInitials("William Sanders"));
console.log(getUserInitials("Grey Charles"));



or you can split by "of" first, and then split by whitespaces:


function getUserInitials(name) {
    const [firstName, lastName] = name.split('of')[0].trim().split(' ');

    return `${firstName[0]}${lastName[0]}`.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(getUserInitials("Joshua Jones of USA"));
console.log(getUserInitials("William Sanders"));
console.log(getUserInitials("Grey Charles"));




Sorry but what if the name is "Carlos James Thomas of Russia", it should get output as "CT"
