Getting First Letters of First Name and Last Name in JS
I wanted to retrieve the first letters of a person's first name and last name using modern JavaScript syntax. Currently, I'm able to retrieve the first letter of the first name and the first letter of the last name correctly.
My problem is that if there is more than one first name, I can't retrieve it correctly.
Code


const names = ["Joshua Jones of USA", "William Sanders", "Grey Charles", "Carlos James Thomas of Russia", "Peter John Parker", "Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez III of Spain"];

function getUserInitials(name) {
  return name.split(' ').map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase()).splice(0, 2);
}

for (const name of names)
  console.log(getUserInitials(name));



Expected Output
JJ, WS, GC, CT, PP, JL

In my solution, I completely split the name along the conjunctions and keep only the beginning. Subsequently, at every word consisting of multiple capital letters, I also separate them. From these names, I concatenate the first and last capital letters and return the result.
Solution # 1


function getUserInitials(name) {
  // Clean up the name: remove titles, conjunctions, and punctuation
  // Carlos James Thomas of Russia ---> Carlos James Thomas
  name = name.replace(/(?:\b(?:of|the|and|in|on|at|for|with)\b|[,\.]).*$/gi, '');
  
  // Remove all-uppercase words (e.g., III)
  // Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez III, Mexico ---> Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez
  name = name.replace(/\b[A-Z]+\b.*$/g, '');
  
  // Remove whitespaces
  name = name.trim();
  
  // Get names
  const words = name.split(' ');

  // Get first char from First and Last name
  let result = '';
  result += words[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  if (words.length > 1) result += words[words.length - 1].charAt(0).toUpperCase();

  return result;
}

// Test cases
const names = [
  "Joshua Jones of USA",
  "William Sanders",
  "Grey Charles",
  "Carlos James Thomas of Russia",
  "Peter John Parker",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez III of Spain",
];

for (const name of names) {
  console.log(getUserInitials(name));
}



Solution # 2
Instead of filtering out entirely capitalized words, let's filter out only Roman numerals.


function getUserInitials(name) {
  // Clean up the name: remove titles, conjunctions, and punctuation
  // Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez III of Spain ---> Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez III
  name = name.replace(/(?:\b(?:of|the|and|in|on|at|for|with)\b).*$/gi, '');

  // Remove Jr. / Sr.
  name = name.replace(/\b(?:Jr|Sr)\.?\b/g, '').replace(/\s*\./g, '');
  
  // Remove Roman numerals
  // Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez III ---> Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez
  // Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez III Another Name ---> Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez  Another Name
  name = name.replace(/\b(?:M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\b/g, '');
  
  // Just tip: After removing the Roman numerals, double spaces were left in place, so from there, we can trim the string if desired
  // Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez  Another Name ---> Juan Carlos Tenaz Lopez
  name = name.replace(/\s{2}.*$/g, '');
  
  // Remove whitespaces
  name = name.trim();
  
  // Get names
  const words = name.split(' ');

  // Get first char from First and Last name
  let result = '';
  result += words[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  if (words.length > 1) result += words[words.length - 1].charAt(0).toUpperCase();

  return result;
}

// Test cases
const names = [
  "Joshua Jones of USA",
  "William Sanders",
  "Grey Charles",
  "Carlos James Thomas of Russia",
  "Peter John Parker",
  "PETER JOHN PARKER",
  "Jr. Peter Parker",
  "Jr Peter Parker",
  "Sr. Peter Parer",
  "Sr Peter Parker",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ I",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ MMM EXAMPLE",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ I of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ II of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ III of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ IV of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ V of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ VI of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ IX of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ X of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ XVI of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ XXX of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ XL of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ CLX of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ CD of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ CM of Spain",
  "Juan Carlos Tenaz LOPEZ MMMCDXVIII of Spain",
];

for (const name of names) {
  console.log(getUserInitials(name));
}




This will fail if any of the names is one of the things your first regex removes. e.g. "William In" // results in "WW".

I didn't check if the array contains only 1 element, so the first and last ones matched.

Also this would make it mandatory the data never have all-capital names, like "PETER SMITH".

This is also true. It's possible to devise other logic for Roman numerals, although from the question, it seemed clear to me that we should only consider the capital first letter format.

@connexo. Pls consider this. This should still work. capital names, like "PETER SMITH"

@Joseph changed.

It has to be pointed out that this will still only solve a very small subset of possible names in the real world.

@rozsazoltan. One more thing I forget, can you include jr or sr? Ex: Peter Parker jr. Output would be "PP"

@Joseph, Do all suffixes in your format end with a dot (.)? So, should we filter out all words ending with a dot from the name (e.g., J., B., as well as Jr., Sr.)? Or would you like to list these abbreviations specifically that you want to filter out?

@rozsazoltan.  Just filter out the jr/jr. or sr/sr. Sometimes users miss out the dot. So yeah just list down the abbreviations

@Joseph, Sorry for the late answer, it was a family party. I've added it as you requested. I had to remove the dot separately because of the regex peculiarity, although I believe there's no name where it's normal to have a dot.
